# How to batch, "if computer has recently rebooted, then do nothing, else reboot"

Tags: batch-file, time, cmd, reboot

I want the computer to reboot, but I only if it hasn't been (manually) rebooted after 12:00 (24h). I can't get the script working with ***systeminfo | findstr /C:"System Boot Time"*** though, it does work with ***%TIME%*** but this variable needs to be changed to actual reboot time.

```
@echo off
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set reboottime=%%a:%%b)
if %reboottime% LSS 12:00 (
Goto :reboot) 
) else (
    GoTo :noreboot
)

::****************************************************************************************
:reboot
shutdown /r /f /t 60
)
Exit /b
::****************************************************************************************
:noreboot
(echo 'no reboot required')
Exit /b
::****************************************************************************************
```

Comment: To find out the last bootup time, please have a look here: [How can I find out when Windows was last restarted?](https://superuser.com/q/523726/146810) There are a couple of different approaches listed in the answers.

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,3 delims=. " %%a in ('
        "wmic os get LastBootUpTime,LocalDateTime"
    ') do if not "%%b"=="" (
        set "bootUpTime=%%a"
        set "currentTime=%%b"
    )

    rem If last reboot was not today, reboot
    if not "%bootUpTime:~0,8%"=="%currentTime:~0,8%" (
        shutdown /r /f /t 60
    ) else (
        echo No reboot required
    )
```

The `for /f` command executes the `wmic` command line tool to retrieve the last boot time and the local time. The output format for the used query is

```
LastBootUpTime             LocalDateTime
20170417110928.382430+120  20170505132724.993000+120
```

This output determine the options used in the `for /f` command. We need to skip the headers line (`skip=1`), and split the next line using spaces and dots as delimiters (`delims=.`), so we have

```
              v          vv              v              delimiters
20170417110928.382430+120  20170505132724.993000+120
1 = %%a        2           3 = %%b        4             tokens
```

By reqesting tokens 1 and 3 we retrieve the two timestamps into `%%a` (the indicated `for` replaceable parameter) and `%%b` (the next replaceable parameter), that we will store into two variables to later select only the date (we can not do substring operations on replaceable parameters). As the output of the `wmic` command also contains ending *empty lines*, a `if` command is used to prevent processing those lines.

With the two timestamps, we only need to retrieve and compare the first eight characters (`yyyymmdd`) to see if the last boot date and current date match. If not, reboot.

**edited** It seems I did misunderstood the indicated hour. Previous code handles the `00:00`/`12:00 midnight` case. For `12:00 noon` case

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,3 delims=. " %%a in ('
        "wmic os get LastBootUpTime,LocalDateTime"
    ') do if not "%%b"=="" (
        set "bootUpTime=%%a"
        set "currentTime=%%b"
    )

    rem Calc how many days since last reboot
    call :julianDate %currentTime:~0,4% %currentTime:~4,2% %currentTime:~6,2% ct
    call :julianDate %bootUpTime:~0,4% %bootUpTime:~4,2% %bootUpTime:~6,2%  bt
    set /a "upTimeDays=ct-bt"

    rem Assume we do not have to reboot and check
    set "requireReboot="

    rem last reboot was today 
    if %upTimeDays% equ 0 (
        if "%currentTime:~8,6%" gtr "120000" if "%bootUpTime:~8,6%" lss "120000" set "requireReboot=1"

    rem last reboot was yesterday
    ) else if %upTimeDays% equ 1 (
        if "%bootUpTime:~8,6%" lss "120000" set "requireReboot=1"
        if "%currentTime:~8,6%" gtr "120000" set "requireReboot=1"

    rem last reboot was more than one day before
    ) else (
        set "requireReboot=1"
    )

    if defined requireReboot (
        echo shutdown /r /f /t 60
    ) else (
        echo No reboot required
    )

    goto :eof

:julianDate year month day returnVar
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set /a "d=100%~3%%100, m=100%~2%%100, a=(14-m)/12, y=%~1+4800-a, m=m+12*a-3"
    set /a "jd=d+(153*m+2)/5+365*y+y/4-y/100+y/400-32045"
    endlocal & set "%~4=%jd%" & goto :eof
```

Comment: _My understanding is that they wish to know if it has booted since noon, not during the same day._

Comment: `if "%bootuptime%" gtr "%currenttime:~0,8%1200" ...`

Comment: @Compo, I saw the `12:00 (24h)` as `00:00`, but reading again may be you are right so answer updated. Thank you

Comment: @Stephan, there are some more cases to handle, but it was a good idea.